# code block getting executed twice in a single threaded program

Tags: java

In my below program i observe that the value of `score` variable is twice(999000 instead of 499500) it's expected value. Closer look at it suggests that the computation is done twice even though the `flag` gets set to true after the first invocation. Any idea what is going wrong here? The program is single threaded. Actual computation involves invoking a rest API, but for testing purpose i have removed it.

```
public class DataClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(CalculationCache.getScore());
  }
}
class CalculationCache{

static{

    computeScore();
}

private static int score;

public static int getScore() {

    computeScore();
    return score;
}

private static boolean flag=false;

static void computeScore(){

    if(!flag) {
        //calculate the score
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            score = score + i;
            flag = true;
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: This looks to be a question where looking directly at the bytecode produced by the Java compiler would probably be very useful.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why? Simple rules about initialization and static blocks is sufficient.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: if only to see those rules in action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to the ordering of class initialization. The static initializers are executed in the order they are defined. The variable `flag` is initialized only after `computeScore()` is invoked. Hence `flag` will be `false` when the method is called the second time. You might want to get rid of the static block

```
static{
    computeScore();
}
```

if you want lazy initialization.

Comment: *The variable flag is initialized only after computeScore() is invoked* is not true as it would break java rules about intialization. Actually flag is default initialized to false the first time computeScore is called, and then is statically initialized to false as defined at the second call.

Comment: @chattambigeek Upvote/accept the answer if it you think it was helpful.